# Can I use Google Wallet for digital goods API to process payments in the background?

Tags: api, payment-gateway, payment-processing, android-pay

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/

The pricing model is very attractive, but I want to use my own payment forms.

Is there currently a way to pass the buyer's credentials from our forms to the API for background processing, or are there any plans to make this option available in the future?

I do understand that through this method, I'd be forgoing the convenience for buyers to utilize their Google Wallet accts if they have one.  However, I think the forms we use will convert higher for us (and for Google).  Would prefer using the API to charge cards in the background a la a Merchant Account, or Paypal Payments Pro.  Will want to integrate saved cards for future purchases as well.

Is this possible today, or should it be in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you're specifically looking at that API (Wallet for Digital). You can take a look at [Wallet for Online Commerce](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/overview) where you maybe closer to what you want....

Its still based on the "Google Wallet" is where users store their payment info (and is therefore not a "credit card gateway/processing service" like the services you mention) but you do have more control...

Hth...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ed.  Wondering if I can pass credit card details to google in the background and run a successful charge, without using the Wallet frontend at all.  Any idea if that would be possible?

Comment: It's actually the other way around. The Google Wallet premise is that the Google user is *sending you* data securely stored in their Google Account. What you are looking for is a "standard" credit card processing gateway service (Google Wallet isn't such a service). Hth....